# MYSQL calculating an average on a count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, average

I have a simple query that I want an average on. This is what it looks like now, and I want to know the average of my count per Opname_OpnameID.

```
SELECT Opname_OpnameID, count(*) as 'behandelingen per opname'
FROM behandeling
GROUP BY Opname_OpnameID
```

Comment: `select avg("behandelingen per opname") from (your existing Select) dt`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the average count, presumably over the entire table, then just do exactly that:

```
SELECT AVG(cnt) AS total_avg
FROM ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM behandeling GROUP BY Opname_OpnameID
) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count(distinct)` and not use a subquery:

```
SELECT count(*) / count(distinct Opname_OpnameID)
FROM behandeling
```